# Typing more python code after running a script

Tags: python

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this. I use TextWrangle to write my Python script and then use terminal to run it. So, I just run something like `python code.py`. In my script, I'm doing some data analysis where I create variables, but then I want to plot a few different things after running the script. So basically, is there a way I can enter a way to enter into a dynamic python mode so I can then plot different things or add more code. I would rather not just add more lines in the script since it takes time to run the script.

For example, at the end of the script, I have created the variables `time, amp1, amp2, phase1, phase2, freq1, freq2`. And I may want to plot different things together like `time` vs `amp1` or any other combination. In terminal, if I type `python` it will enter into python mode where I could type out the entire script again and then plot different things and keep all the variables saved, but is there a way to keep all the variables saves locally after running the script?

Comment: `python -i code.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdb.set_trace()` at the end of the script in order to enter into interactive debug mode. It is a bit of an abuse of the module, but it will let you write code and manipulate the current scope